# What's the cause of my segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, structure

I'm trying to write a program that reads in entries from a file into a dynamically allocated array of structures using input redirection.  My program compiles fine but I'm getting a segmentation fault and I'm having trouble finding the cause.

Here's my Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct StudentData
{
char* name;
char* major;
double gpa;
} Student;

int main()
{
Student* data = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student)*5);

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
 // allocate memory for name and read input
 data[i].name = malloc(50);
 *(data+i)->name == scanf("%s", (char*)&data[i].name);

 // allocate memory for major and read input
 data[i].major = malloc(30);
 *(data+i)->major == scanf("%s", (char*)&data[i].major);

 // read input for gpa
 (data+i)->gpa == scanf("%lf", &data[i].gpa); 

 //print array
 printf("%s\n%s\n%f\n", data[i].name, data[i].major, data[i].gpa);
 }
}
```

Any clues?  If it seems obvious it's because I'm relatively new to C!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*(data+i)->name == scanf("%s", (char*)&data[i].name);
```

What are you comparing the return value of `scanf` for? Just remove the first part. Also, `data[i].name` is already a pointer, so you shouldn't take the address once again. It should just be:

```
scanf("%s", data[i].name);  // no & because name is already a pointer
```

And similarly:

```
scanf("%s", data[i].major);
scanf("%lf", &data[i].gpa);  // & here because gpa is just a double
```

Comment: I feel like an ignoramus now but that helped me out tremendously.  Program runs like a charm now.  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
*(data+i)->name == scanf("%s", (char*)&data[i].name);
```

Ignoring the weird and void `==` for a moment, `&data[i].name` is wrong since you're taking an address of a pointer. `data[i].name` would be sufficient here, since the `name` field is already an address `scanf` can write into.

And the cast to `(char*)` is what probably *shuts the compiler up about it* - did you enter it for this purpose :-) ? Because `&data[i].name` has the type `char**`, which `scanf` wouldn't accept, unless you forcefully casted it to `char*`.

As a general advice, try to avoid `scanf` - it leads to very unsafe code (as you've just seen!) Instead, use `fgets` to read a line (from the standard input too) and then break this line into its constituents. This may initially take a bit more code to implement, but leads to much safer and more predictable code.

Comment: I'll def. be sticking with fgets from now on.  Thanks for the quick response.  I learned a lot just now.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Adam: Don't sprinkle casts around to shut up the compiler.  If you get a warning, there's almost certainly a good reason for it; casts should be used sparingly, and only if you really know exactly why you're doing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is some unnecessary code being used with scanf, like `*(data+i)->name ==`.  That doesn't do anything useful (and is probably causing the segfault).  If it weren't causing access errors, it would compare the return value of scanf with the pointer and then ignore the result of the comparison.  (A decent compiler would have warned about this.)

After getting rid of the excess code, it will be technically okay, except there is nothing to prevent buffer overrun.  That's done either by controlling the input data, or adding limits to the lengths of the strings, like with `scanf("%50s", data[i].name);`

Comment: Not sure what I was thinking with the ==.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Program runs great now.  Thank you so much.

Comment: I removed an excess `&` in the scanf parameter list.  `.name` is already a pointer to the data; an ampersand here will also cause problems.  Namely, writing the input characters to the data structure where the name field pointer is.

Answer (score 0):

`&data[i].name` and `&data[i].major` are of type `char **`, so you cannot safely cast it to `char *`.

Losing the ampersand will correct your error.

There are also other logical errors with the use of scanf(), but that's probably overwhelming - it'd be nice if you revisited this code once you entered a name of more than 50 characters.

Comment: I couldn't understand why the compiler was recognizing it as char**.  Now that makes sense.  Thanks a bunch.